# Intercalar dois arrays em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Imagine que eu tenha dois arrays:

```
var array1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var array2 = ['123', '456', '789'];
```

Eu posso utilizar a função [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) para juntar ambos os arrays um depois do outro, exemplo:

```
array1.concat(array2) // ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', '123', '456', '789']
```

Mas como conseguiria **intercalar** os valores dos arrays? Existe alguma função em JavaScript para junta-los de forma que os valores de ambos se misturem? Exemplo:

```
array1.intercalate(array2) //['abc', '123', 'def', '456', 'ghi', '789']
```

Comment: Você quer seguir essa ordem mesmo? array1, array2, array1, array2... etc

Comment: Esses arrays tem sempre o mesmo tamanho?

Comment: @Randrade Sim, sempre esta ordem.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Não. Um pode ser menor que o outro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não existe função nativa para isso, mas você pode construir uma:

```js
var array1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var array2 = ['123', '456', '789'];

if(!Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty('interpolate')) {
  Array.prototype.interpolate = function(other) {
    var limit = this.length < other.length ? other.length : this.length;
    var out = [];
  
    for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      if(this.length > 0) out.push(this.shift());
      if(other.length > 0) out.push(other.shift());
    }
    
    return out;
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(array1.interpolate(array2));
```

E valem os alertas do @Pablo abaixo: se não tiver controle sobre o uso do código e/ou não souber bem o que está fazendo, crie a função fora do `prototype` (e passe outro array para usar no lugar de `this`).

Comment: Eu tava mesmo pensando nisso, e tu ja respondeu ^^

Comment: Vale lembrar dos [perigos de extender objetos padrão](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Comment: @Pablo Coloquei uma guarda caso esse método se torne padrão no futuro. Fora isso, [não vejo muito problema](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/).

Comment: @bfavaretto Se você é dono(a) da base e sabe bem os riscos, não tem problema, mas tem muito for..in desavisado por aí. Prefiro não arriscar

Comment: @Pablo Ainda dá pra deixar o método não-enumerável e escapar dos `for..in`. Só não vai funcionar em implementações pré-ES5.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pois é... tenho que me virar com ES3 aqui...

Comment: @Pablo Acrescentei um alerta no final da resposta para que ninguém saia daqui desavisado.

Answer (score 6):

Da para você criar uma função simples para resolver isso, fiz um exemplo aqui, ainda não testei vários casos mas para o seu problema apresentado resolve.

### Exemplo:

```js
var array1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var array2 = ['123', '456', '789'];


function intercale(array1, array2) {
  var arrayResult = [];
  var total = 0;
  if (array1.length > array2.length) {
    total = array1.length;
  } else {
    total = array2.length;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (array1[i]) {
      arrayResult.push(array1[i]);
    }
    if (array2[i]) {
      arrayResult.push(array2[i]);
    }
  }

  return arrayResult;
}


document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(intercale(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assim também funciona e minimiza o código:

```
var array1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var array2 = ['123', '456', '789'];

function arrayIntersect(array1, array2) {

   var arr_join = [],arr = array1.map((res, i) => { 

          arr_join.push(res);
          if (array2[i]) {
             arr_join.push(array2[i]);
          }
          return arr_join;

   }); 
     return arr[0];
}
arrayIntersect(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra solução pequena e que parece funcionar bem em vários cenários:

```
function arrayIntercale(arr1, arr2, arr3=[]) {
    
    if (arr1.length == 0) return arr3;

    arr3.push(arr1.shift());

    if (arr2.length != 0) arr3.push(arr2.shift());

    return arrayIntercale(arr1, arr2, arr3);
}
```