# Método Zip() do .NET em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Eu estava lendo essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436595/para-que-serve-o-zip-de-enumerable-em-net) e reparei que não há o [método `Zip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) no JavaScript, gostaria de saber como implementar um método que funcione da mesma forma ou se há alguma outra função que faça o mesmo trabalho sem utilização de alguma lib externa.

Comment: Relacionado: [Intercalar dois arrays em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110391/112052)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não tem pronto mesmo, mas no fundo é só mapear, o que muitos já fazem.

Me parece que algo assim resolve a maioria dos casos, mas esses algoritmos podem se complicar em casos extremos, o jeito simples:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];
console.log(array1.map((value, i) => value * array2[i]));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Zip.js).

Obviamente que pode criar uma função chamada `zip()` e encapsular essa lógica dando mais semântica ao que pretende, e aí pode até colocar em um protótipo para ficar disponível para qualquer *array* e assim pode chamar pelo objeto, e óbvio, pode ir sofisticando e generalizando conforme vai precisando.

[Para entender mais sobre o zip](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/436595/101).

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução seria criar uma função que recebe um array e a função que é aplicada aos elementos. Você pode adicionar no *prototype* de [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) para que ela fique disponível para qualquer array:

```js
Array.prototype.zip = function(v, func) {
    let len = Math.min(this.length, v.length); // pegar o tamanho do menor array
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // chamar a função passando os elementos de cada um dos arrays
        result.push(func(this[i], v[i]));
    }
    return result;
}

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let words = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

let v = numbers.zip(words, (a, b) => `${a} - ${b}`);
v.forEach(s => console.log(s));
```

Eu coloquei uma condição para considerar o tamanho do menor array, caso eles tenham tamanhos diferentes, pois segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8), é isso que ele faz:

> *If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements*

Ou seja, se um array tem tamanho 3 e o outro 4, o quarto elemento do maior array é ignorado, e o array retornado terá apenas 3 elementos.